# TypeError: Object of type 'Entities' is not JSON serializable IBM Cloud natural language understanding

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
import watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding.features.v1 \
as Features

natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
username="username",
password="password",
version="2017-02-27")

response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
text="IBM is an American multinational technology company headquartered \
in Armonk, New York, United States, with operations in over 170 \
countries.",
features=[
Features.Entities(
  emotion=True,
  sentiment=True,
  limit=2
),
Features.Keywords(
  emotion=True,
  sentiment=True,
  limit=2
)
 ]
 )

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

I am new to IBM watson API .....i was trying this sample code provided by them by I was getting this error

> **TypeError: Object of type 'Entities' is not JSON serializable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution from the IBM developer works 
[here is the link](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/413726/typeerror-object-of-type-entities-is-not-json-seri.html#)

just replace

```
features=[
   Features.Entities(
          emotion=True,
          sentiment=True,
           limit=2
    ),
   Features.Keywords(
           emotion=True,
           sentiment=True,
           limit=2
    )
]
```

with :

```
features=Features(entities=EntitiesOptions(
                      emotion=True, sentiment=True,limit=2), 
               keywords=KeywordsOptions(
                      emotion=True, sentiment=True,limit=2
                                ))
```

this is due to the changes done in v 1 python sdk 
[Here is the link showing the changes made in v 1 python sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/wiki/Migration)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issues by dumping `response.result` instead of just `response`.

The [API guide](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#post-analyze) wrongly says to use: `print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))`

When reviewing the [docstring in the source code](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/002e16d799f5da088e690a47d4e5d6a01e090f29/watson_developer_cloud/visual_recognition_v3.py#L130) I found the  `DetailedResponse`type contains 'result, headers and HTTP status code'.

I think the example in the API documentation needs to be updated so it doesn't mislead people.

Answer (score 1):

All depends on what you insert in your text parameter. Do you use the same text?

I used the example from the API reference with the same phrase for this answer... but, JSON knows only how to handle Unicode strings, not byte sequences. Either transform into Unicode `(json.dumps(response.decode("utf-8"), indent=2))`, or if is one integer array `(json.dumps(list(response)))`. You also can try `print(json.dumps(list(response.values())))`.

So, this is one step-by-step for using the NLU service with Python.

**IBM Cloud** (New name for *IBM Bluemix*)

- Create one [account](https://console.bluemix.net/registration/) (Now, you can create without a credit card and use the LITE plan for Watson and other Services!)
- Catalog -> Watson -> Natural Language Understanding service -> Create -> Service Credentials

In your PC, after installed Python, try to run the command in the CMD/Terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud
```

Using the same code provided from the [API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/?python#post-analyze):

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
import watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding.features.v1 \
  as Features

natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
  username="username from the NLU -> Service Credentials",
  password="passoword from the NLU -> Service Credentials",
  version="2017-02-27")

response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
  text="IBM is an American multinational technology company headquartered \
    in Armonk, New York, United States, with operations in over 170 \
    countries.",
  features=[
    Features.Entities(
      emotion=True,
      sentiment=True,
      limit=2
    ),
    Features.Keywords(
      emotion=True,
      sentiment=True,
      limit=2
    )
  ]
)

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

And the return when I run the command `python NLUAnalyze.py` in CMD is:

```
{
  "usage": {
    "text_units": 1,
    "text_characters": 148,
    "features": 2
  },
  "language": "en",
  "keywords": [
    {
      "text": "American multinational technology",
      "sentiment": {
        "score": 0.0,
        "label": "neutral"
      },
      "relevance": 0.993518,
      "emotion": {
        "sadness": 0.085259,
        "joy": 0.026169,
        "fear": 0.02454,
        "disgust": 0.088711,
        "anger": 0.033078
      }
    },
    {
      "text": "New York",
      "sentiment": {
        "score": 0.0,
        "label": "neutral"
      },
      "relevance": 0.613816,
      "emotion": {
        "sadness": 0.166741,
        "joy": 0.228903,
        "fear": 0.057987,
        "disgust": 0.050965,
        "anger": 0.054653
      }
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "type": "Company",
      "text": "IBM",
      "sentiment": {
        "score": 0.0,
        "label": "neutral"
      },
      "relevance": 0.33,
      "emotion": {
        "sadness": 0.085259,
        "joy": 0.026169,
        "fear": 0.02454,
        "disgust": 0.088711,
        "anger": 0.033078
      },
      "disambiguation": {
        "subtype": [
          "SoftwareLicense",
          "OperatingSystemDeveloper",
          "ProcessorManufacturer",
          "SoftwareDeveloper",
          "CompanyFounder",
          "ProgrammingLanguageDesigner",
          "ProgrammingLanguageDeveloper"
        ],
        "name": "IBM",
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/IBM"
      },
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

- See the Official [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/?python) using Python.
- See the Official Documentation for using [Natural Language Understanding](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/index.html#features).

Comment: Thank you for responding ....i tried both the methods suggested by you.........
 (json.dumps(response.decode("utf-8"), indent=2)) and (json.dumps(list(response)))   but none of them worked

Comment: is there any other way ??

Comment: can you please show one part of what you want to send? and I'll see the type that you're use and try to help u

Comment: I am sending the default text set by IBM reference code...."IBM is an American multinational technology company headquartered \
    in Armonk, New York, United States, with operations in over 170 \
    countries." ---------This one

Comment: Can you please copy my code and replace with your service credentials? Just for one test.

Comment: but without the ( - ) in your username, just "219xxxc8xxxxxxxxxxxxxx31" and "cz7xxxxVsFp". What is your python version?

Comment: please delete your comment with your credentials for your self security

Comment: I had tried it without the ( - )................my version is python 3.6.3

Comment: So, let's go to some steps... try to install the watson-developer-cloud again with the pip install in the `cmd`, then, create one new folder in your `Desktop`, install the Sublime Text (code editor), open and paste my CODE, and replace with your service credentials. After it, `Ctrl + S` and save with: `NLUExample.py`. Open your cmd and navigate to the folder in your desktop `cd Desktop/yourFolder`, and type the command: `python NLUExample.py`

Comment: i tried  "pip3 install --upgrade json "  and i am getting an error...... "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for json"............can this be a reason??

Comment: In this case not, is just one message that don't have new version. So, if my steps didn't work, try to use this code `print(json.dumps(list(response.values())))` instead of `print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))`. If don't work yet, try to reinstall Python in your computer

Comment: python3 archive.py  --- >  " python3: can't open file 'archive.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"